# How to access box drawing characters in ascii in c++ on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, ascii

The character I'm first looking for is usually 201 in normal ascii code, but its different for mac. How do i work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This character in not available in any single byte character set on OS X.

Unlike the Windows environment (which require special coding to use Unicode), Unicode is readily available in OS X.

Use Unicode U+2554 or UTF-8 E2 95 94

You can just use the following in a character or string ╔

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to input the Unicode characters on a Mac by [switching to the Unicode Hex Input keyboard layout](http://www.poynton.com/notes/misc/mac-unicode-hex-input.html).

1. Open system preferences
2. Choose keyboard
3. Add Unicode Hex Input to the list
4. Select "Show Input menu in menu bar"
5. Close the preferences
6. Click on the flag that's appeared in the menu bar
7. Select Unicode Hex Input

Then you need the codes and you can find a nice summary of the [box codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) here at Wikipedia.

To enter a code:

1. Hold down Option (alt)
2. Type the code, without the preceding U, i.e for U+2560, type 2560
3. Release Option

I drew this example using that method: ╠╩╬╩╣

After you're finished, you can change your keyboard input back to your normal one using the flag in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as ASCII character 201. ASCII is a 7-bit single byte character encoding, where code points go from 0 to 127, inclusive. Maybe you are referring to “╔” in the original IBM PC character set?

Then you can do this:

1. Use a Windows PC with a keyboard that has a numeric keypad.
2. In a console window with input (e.g. the command interpreter), hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type <kbd>201</kbd> on the numeric keypad, in number mode (NumLock on).
3. Start Word or Windows’ WordPad.
4. Copy and paste the character into Word or WordPad.
5. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

On my laptop WordPad reports 2554, which means it's Unicode character U+2554 (hexadecimal).

In C++ you can express that character as `L'\u2554'`, which is of type `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if you prefer names to numbers, [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) has supported double- and thick-line drawing characters in Unicode terminals since [late 2009](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#index-t20091003).  That is after the (rather old) ncurses 5.7 bundled with OSX, but newer releases are available with MacPorts, etc.

Here are a couple of screenshots to illustrate:

[image]

[image]